# Large number of files renamed by logrotate by mistake, and compressed n times. Rename them correctly

Tags: bash, shell, awk, find, posix

Logrotate has compressed files that already existed compressed n times and renamed them wrongly.

An example of a misnamed file is the following:

`v_virtual.log.5.gz.1.gz.1.gz.2.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz`

My intention is to do a search for each file (they are not necessarily called v_virtual) but what I want is to modify the name leaving the main name in this example `v_virtual`, with date and extension .gz

It should look like this:

`v_virtual.log_2020-08-20.gz`

The date would be the day of creation of said file.

I've been doing it by separating each file, by its names, using awk, paste and others, but I would like to do it with a script that would make it much faster.

Could you give me a hand?

Comment: you could use `sed` or [parameter expansion](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Parameters#Parameter_Expansion) or `rename` command (if it is perl based) to search for `.gz` and everything after and replace it with `.gz`

Comment: i didn't know that gzip doesn't have checks against double compression

Answer (score 0):

needs improvement for non-trivial file names (`ls` is not the best idea)

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in ./*.gz.[0-9].gz
  do
    test -f "$file" || continue
    file="${file##*/}"
    mtime=$(stat -c%y "$file")
    mtime=${mtime:0:10}
    name="${file%%.[0-9].gz*}"

    while gzip -t "$name"*.gz.[0-9].gz 2> /dev/null
      do
        out="$(ls -1 "$name"*.gz.[0-9].gz | head -n1)"
        gzip -d "$out"
        mv "${out%*.gz}" "${out%.[0-9].gz}"
    done
    mv -b "${out%.[0-9].gz}" "${name}_${mtime}.gz"

#    echo "'$file' -> '${name}_${mtime}.gz'"
done
```

assuming the suffix pattern is always `.1.gz` the script will loop over each file `gunzip` recursively and delete `.1` from file name, until there is only one suffix left. when the loop is finished, creation date is added to file name

```
gzip -d v_virtual.log.5.gz.1.gz.1.gz.2.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz
mv v_virtual.log.5.gz.1.gz.1.gz.2.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1 v_virtual.log.5.gz.1.gz.1.gz.2.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz
gzip -d v_virtual.log.5.gz.1.gz.1.gz.2.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz
mv v_virtual.log.5.gz.1.gz.1.gz.2.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1 v_virtual.log.5.gz.1.gz.1.gz.2.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz
gzip -d v_virtual.log.5.gz.1.gz.1.gz.2.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz
mv v_virtual.log.5.gz.1.gz.1.gz.2.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1 v_virtual.log.5.gz.1.gz.1.gz.2.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz
gzip -d v_virtual.log.5.gz.1.gz.1.gz.2.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz
mv v_virtual.log.5.gz.1.gz.1.gz.2.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1 v_virtual.log.5.gz.1.gz.1.gz.2.gz.1.gz.1.gz
gzip -d v_virtual.log.5.gz.1.gz.1.gz.2.gz.1.gz.1.gz
mv v_virtual.log.5.gz.1.gz.1.gz.2.gz.1.gz.1 v_virtual.log.5.gz.1.gz.1.gz.2.gz.1.gz
gzip -d v_virtual.log.5.gz.1.gz.1.gz.2.gz.1.gz
mv v_virtual.log.5.gz.1.gz.1.gz.2.gz.1 v_virtual.log.5.gz.1.gz.1.gz.2.gz
gzip -d v_virtual.log.5.gz.1.gz.1.gz.2.gz
mv v_virtual.log.5.gz.1.gz.1.gz.2 v_virtual.log.5.gz.1.gz.1.gz
gzip -d v_virtual.log.5.gz.1.gz.1.gz
mv v_virtual.log.5.gz.1.gz.1 v_virtual.log.5.gz.1.gz
gzip -d v_virtual.log.5.gz.1.gz
mv v_virtual.log.5.gz.1 v_virtual.log.5.gz

mv -b v_virtual.log.5.gz v_virtual.log_2020-08-20.gz
```